# React when useState change react-complex-tree not rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state, use-state

codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/gallant-feistel-4tf5x?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

- I am using react-complex-tree to show my XML in tree format. I want to add button called ExpandAllTree

  const [expandedItems,setExpandedItems] = useState([]);

I am holding my tree Items here

```
const traverseXml = (treeData, xmlObject) => {
    treeData[xmlObject.name] = {
        index: xmlObject.name,
        canMove: false,
        hasChildren: !!xmlObject.children.length,
        children: xmlObject.children.map(c => c.name),
        data: !xmlObject.children.length ? `${xmlObject.name}: ${xmlObject.value}` : xmlObject.name,
        canRename: false
    };

    if (!xmlObject.children.isEmpty) {
        xmlObject.children.forEach(c => {
            setExpandedItems(oldArray => [...oldArray,xmlObject.name]);
            traverseXml(treeData, c);
        });
    }
};
```

this code piece does travel all XML and create a data for react-complex-tree and also gets all Id's of tree element with

```
setExpandedItems(oldArray => [...oldArray,xmlObject.name]);
```

This part works perfect.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setExpandedItems([]);
    traverseXml(firstTreeData, DocumentXml);
    traverseXml(secondTreeData, AppHdrXml);
    }, [treeOpen]);

const handleOpenClick = () => {
    setTreeOpen(!treeOpen);
}
```

whenever a button hits it should rerender. But It is not rendering. when I check the logs on first time page open
expandedItems is empty like an expected when I press the button expandedItems to get all tree IDs like expected again but in frontend nothings changes.

```
<UncontrolledTreeEnvironment
                    canDragAndDrop={true}
                    canDropOnItemWithChildren={true}
                    canReorderItems={true}
                    dataProvider={new StaticTreeDataProvider(secondTreeData, (item, data) => ({...item, data}))}
                    getItemTitle={item => item.data}
                    viewState={{
                        ['Apphdr']: {
                            expandedItems:expandedItems
                        },
                    }}
                >
                    <Tree treeId={"Apphdr"} rootItem={"AppHdr"}/>
                </UncontrolledTreeEnvironment>
```

And there is no mistake on data type with expandedItems because when I give data manually which expandedItems gets,  Tree shows as expanded.

Comment: I don't see any overt issues with how you are updating state. To confirm, you've verified/validated that the `expendedItems` state array is correctly updated to what you want? After reading up on the `react-complex-tree` docs I also don't see any overt issues there. Think you could create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: It need only be a minimal, reproducible example, nothing proprietary. Basically the above code with dummy data in a complete component would probably be sufficient. If we can resolve the minimal example then the goal is for you to take what is learned and apply it against your larger code.

Comment: Yeap i did that. here is the  [link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/gallant-feistel-4tf5x?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) i am waiting for any help. Thanks

Comment: @DrewReese did u get any chance to look at it ?

Comment: I did. Started researching the docs to try and understand better that packages controlled and uncontrolled environments. You're using an `UncontrolledTreeEnvironment` which to me implies you don't control it, analogous to an uncontrolled input where you pass it a `defaultValue` prop and the input controls itself versus a controlled input where you pass `value` and `onChange` props to "control" the input. Maybe this helps you since you're likely more familiar with `react-complex-tree` than I am. I'll keep digging on this though.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will check this out and report you back. Thanks again

Comment: Thx its solved @DrewReese

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it. Cheers and good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you changed to ControlledTreeEnviroment and set items like

```
items={firstTreeData}
```

Tree start to rerender

Comment: but after this drag and drop won't work unless you manually implement it in ControlledEnvironment. How did you implement it?